# Is there a faster way to write those 3 same queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there any **faster query** way of rewriting these queries or by combining them?

```
update products
set shop = '1' 
where shop LIKE '%demo%'

update products
set shop = '2' 
where shop LIKE '%car%'

update products
set shop = '3' 
where shop LIKE '%art%'
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "faster"? Less code? Faster query? Why is this critical for your application?

Comment: There are some more question in the comment. Why is this important? It seems, that you just want to refactor your db schema, for what speed is not that important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update products
set shop =
case 
when shop like '%demo%' then 1
when shop like '%car%' then 2
when shop like '%art%' then 3
else shop
end
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't necessarily make the query faster than the separate queries, although I'm not convinced they were unbearably slow anyway.

Comment: @Juhana: I agree with you but if, as I think, he just needed to normalize his table and run this query once, this is not a great problem.

Comment: Yes, because in the future I will have to update a lot of `shop` it is kind of stupid to create a query for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a stored procedure: http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_stored_procedure_UPDATE.php